# Delete first occurence of javascript map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I am using javascript and angularJS right now. I have a map where the keys AND the values are variable. So there is no incrementing index, the key is an idea of an object and the value an attribute of the same object.

It is possible that at some point I have two times the same entry in the map like:

```
map[1] = 3
map[1] = 3
```

Now, I want to delete one occurrence of those. Is this possible ? I know `delete map[1]` but this is deleting every occurrence and I want to delete just one :s

Comment: It's impossible to have two entry for the same  index. The second replaces the first one

Comment: Oh yeah haha you're right.